# Transformation between latin squares

Tags: finite-groups, latin-square

Let $L\in R^{k\times k}$ a Latin square matrix. 
Which is the most general form of $A\in R^{k\times k}$ such that
$$
A^TLA=L'
$$
with $L'$ another Latin square?
Thanks!

Fabio

Comment: So you're allowing the entries of your Latin square to be any $k$ different real numbers, possibly different for $L'$ than for $L$?

Answer (score 3):

I doubt that there's a very nice characterization in general.

Let $L$ be any $k \times k$ Latin square matrix (whose entries are $k$ distinct reals).  Let $M$ be a $k \times k$ Latin square with symbolic entries.  For $B = A^T L A$ to be a Latin square with the same pattern as 
$M$, what we need is $B_{i.j} = B_{i'.j'}$ if and only if $M_{i.j} = M_{i',j'}$.
We might start by solving a set of $k(k-1)$ quadratic equations (e.g. taking one $(i',j')$ for each symbol) in the $k^2$ unknowns $a_{ij}$.  We might hope that for a generic solution the entries of $B$ that are not required to be equal will not be equal.  Of course, restricting to real solutions is an additional complication.  In some cases, symmetry dictates there is no solution: if one of $L$ and $M$ is symmetric, the other must also be symmetric.

For example, I tried the case $k=3$ with $L = \pmatrix{1 & 2 & 0\cr 2 & 0 & 1\cr 0 & 1 & 2}$ and $M = \pmatrix{a & b & c\cr b & c & a\cr c & a & b\cr}$ (both symmetric).
We get a set of $3$ equations in $9$ unknowns, which turns out to have Hilbert dimension $6$.  One family of solutions is

$$ A = \pmatrix{a_{1,1} & a_{1,1} & a_{1,1}\cr
                a_{2,1} & a_{2,1} & a_{2,1}\cr
                -2 a_{1,1} & -2 a_{1,1} & -2 a_{1,1}\cr} $$
but this doesn't work as $A^T L A$ has all entries equal.
One $5$-parameter family that does work is
$$ \pmatrix{a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3}\cr
     u/d & v/d & w/d\cr
   -2 a_{1,1} & a_{3,2} & a_{3,3}\cr} $$
where 
$$ \eqalign{u &= 72\,{a_{{1,1}}}^{2}a_{{1,2}}a_{{1,3}}+36\,{a_{{1,1}}}^{2}a_{{1,2}}a_{{
3,3}}+36\,{a_{{1,1}}}^{2}a_{{1,3}}a_{{3,2}}+18\,{a_{{1,1}}}^{2}a_{{3,2
}}a_{{3,3}}-4\,a_{{1,1}}{a_{{1,2}}}^{3}+12\,a_{{1,1}}{a_{{1,2}}}^{2}a_
{{3,2}}+15\,a_{{1,1}}a_{{1,2}}{a_{{3,2}}}^{2}-4\,a_{{1,1}}{a_{{1,3}}}^
{3}+12\,a_{{1,1}}{a_{{1,3}}}^{2}a_{{3,3}}+15\,a_{{1,1}}a_{{1,3}}{a_{{3
,3}}}^{2}+4\,a_{{1,1}}{a_{{3,2}}}^{3}+4\,a_{{1,1}}{a_{{3,3}}}^{3}+9\,{
a_{{3,3}}}^{2}{a_{{1,2}}}^{2}-18\,a_{{3,2}}a_{{1,3}}a_{{3,3}}a_{{1,2}}
+9\,{a_{{3,2}}}^{2}{a_{{1,3}}}^{2}
\cr
v &= 36\,{a_{{1,1}}}^{2}{a_{{1,3}}}^{2}+36\,{a_{{1,1}}}^{2}a_{{1,3}}a_{{3,3
}}+9\,{a_{{1,1}}}^{2}{a_{{3,3}}}^{2}-9\,a_{{1,1}}{a_{{1,2}}}^{2}a_{{3,
3}}+9\,a_{{1,1}}a_{{1,2}}a_{{1,3}}a_{{3,2}}-9/2\,a_{{1,1}}a_{{1,2}}a_{
{3,2}}a_{{3,3}}+9/2\,a_{{1,1}}a_{{1,3}}{a_{{3,2}}}^{2}-2\,{a_{{1,2}}}^
{4}-2\,{a_{{1,2}}}^{3}a_{{3,2}}-9/2\,{a_{{1,2}}}^{2}{a_{{3,2}}}^{2}-2
\,a_{{1,2}}{a_{{1,3}}}^{3}-3\,a_{{1,2}}{a_{{1,3}}}^{2}a_{{3,3}}+3\,a_{
{1,2}}a_{{1,3}}{a_{{3,3}}}^{2}-4\,a_{{1,2}}{a_{{3,2}}}^{3}+2\,a_{{1,2}
}{a_{{3,3}}}^{3}+{a_{{1,3}}}^{3}a_{{3,2}}-15/2\,{a_{{1,3}}}^{2}a_{{3,2
}}a_{{3,3}}-6\,a_{{1,3}}a_{{3,2}}{a_{{3,3}}}^{2}-{a_{{3,2}}}^{4}-a_{{3
,2}}{a_{{3,3}}}^{3}
\cr
w &= 36\,{a_{{1,1}}}^{2}{a_{{1,2}}}^{2}+36\,{a_{{1,1}}}^{2}a_{{1,2}}a_{{3,2
}}+9\,{a_{{1,1}}}^{2}{a_{{3,2}}}^{2}+9\,a_{{1,1}}a_{{1,2}}a_{{1,3}}a_{
{3,3}}+9/2\,a_{{1,1}}a_{{1,2}}{a_{{3,3}}}^{2}-9\,a_{{1,1}}{a_{{1,3}}}^
{2}a_{{3,2}}-9/2\,a_{{1,1}}a_{{1,3}}a_{{3,2}}a_{{3,3}}-2\,{a_{{1,2}}}^
{3}a_{{1,3}}+{a_{{1,2}}}^{3}a_{{3,3}}-3\,{a_{{1,2}}}^{2}a_{{1,3}}a_{{3
,2}}-15/2\,{a_{{1,2}}}^{2}a_{{3,2}}a_{{3,3}}+3\,a_{{1,2}}a_{{1,3}}{a_{
{3,2}}}^{2}-6\,a_{{1,2}}{a_{{3,2}}}^{2}a_{{3,3}}-2\,{a_{{1,3}}}^{4}-2
\,{a_{{1,3}}}^{3}a_{{3,3}}-9/2\,{a_{{1,3}}}^{2}{a_{{3,3}}}^{2}+2\,a_{{
1,3}}{a_{{3,2}}}^{3}-4\,a_{{1,3}}{a_{{3,3}}}^{3}-{a_{{3,2}}}^{3}a_{{3,
3}}-{a_{{3,3}}}^{4}
\cr 
d &= 8\,{a_{{1,2}}}^{3}+12\,{a_{{1,2}}}^{2}a_{{3,2}}+6\,a_{{1,2}}{a_{{3,2}}
}^{2}+8\,{a_{{1,3}}}^{3}+12\,{a_{{1,3}}}^{2}a_{{3,3}}+6\,a_{{1,3}}{a_{
{3,3}}}^{2}+{a_{{3,2}}}^{3}+{a_{{3,3}}}^{3}
\cr}$$
where  some polynomials in the $a_{ij}$ must be nonzero for $B$ to have three distinct entries.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was looking indeed for some simple characterization but could not find it. Here was my (not conclusive) reasoning: if L is a latin square I can write it as: $\sum_i^k P_i v_i$ for some set of permutations $P_i$ such that $\sum _i P_i =J$ the all-ones matrix and $v\in R^k$. Thus using a similar reasoning for $L'$ I can write $\sum_i^k A^TP_iA v_i=\sum_i \tilde{P}_ir_i$ for some set of permutations $\tilde{P}_i$ and $r\in R^k$. From this i wanted to deduce that   $A^TP_iA $ must be a permutation and thus $A$ must be a permutation and $v$ proportional  $r$...